# Cannot append a list to another list when both lists are passed into function as parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append a list to another list inside a python function. Both lists are passed into the function as parameters. 
For example, in below code, I was using `res.append(cur)` but `res` will return empty in this case. Instead I have to use `res.append(cur[:])` to make a deep copy (this is actually a shallow copy corrected in comments). What is weird is that `res.append(cur)` will work had both lists are not passed into the function but instead defined in the function.

I understand `cur[:]` does a deep copy (this is actually a shallow copy corrected in comments) in this case. Does it mean `res.append(cur)` will not append `cur` because it's not a deep copy?

UPDATE:  I have updated the full code below, basically it tries to print a subset of a given list of numbers, both `res` and `cur` are list defined outside `helper()`, so if `cur[:]` returns a shallow copy and it works, why does `res.append(cur)` actually do in this case that does not work?

```
from __future__ import print_function

def subsetsWithDup():
    set_list = [1,2,2]
    res = []
    cur = []
    set_list.sort()

    index = 0
    helper(set_list, index, res, cur)
    # below for loop prints nothing if res.append(cur) is used in helper() instead of res.append(cur[:])
    for r in res:
        print(r)

def helper(set_list, index, res, cur):
    if index == len(set_list):
        if cur not in res:
            res.append(cur) # -> if I change this to res.append(cur[:]) this works
        return

    helper(set_list, index + 1, res, cur)

    cur.append(set_list[index])
    helper(set_list, index + 1, res, cur)
    cur.pop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subsetsWithDup()
```

Comment: try taking cur out of the function

Comment: you create `cur` as an empty list, never modify it, then pass it to `helper`

Comment: `res.append(cur)` will append the list `cur` to `res` and not its content, thus `res` become a list of lists. Is it actually what you try to do? Maybe we need more context and/or a minimal example to highlight the behavior.

Comment: Please post a __real__ [mcve] and define "works" and "doesn't work". Oh and no: `cur[:]` doesn't create a deep copy, only a shallow one.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you, i have checked cur[:] indeed returns a shallow copy

Comment: @keye we're still waiting for the [mcve] !-) (well, if you expect a useful answer at least...)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers hi, I just updated the example. can you help me to take a look? thanks

Comment: @keyes cf my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually not that `res.append(cur)` "doesn't work" - it of course works as expected -, but with *how* it works.

Python's "variables" are not symbolic names for memory locations, they are just name=>object pairs, and the same object can be referenced by many names at once. If you mutate an object thru one of it's name, you'll see the effect thru all the other names it's bound to, because all those names point to the same object:

```
>>> a = list("abc")
>>> a
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b = a
>>> c = b
>>> a is b
True
>>> a is c
True
>>> b.append("d")
>>> c
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> a
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> b
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> c.pop()
'd'
>>> a
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> c
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```

And this works the same for any attribute, collection etc, including of course lists of lists:

```
>>> lst  = [a]
>>> lst[0]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lst[0]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> c.append(42)
>>> lst
[['a', 'b', 'c', 42]]
```

Also, Python *never* implicitely copies anything - when you pass an object to a function, the function gets the object, not a copy of it:

```
>>> def foo(lst):
...     print("in foo, lst = {} (id : {})".format(lst, id(lst)))
...     lst.append([42])
... 
>>> id(a)
140278039812000
>>> foo(a)
in foo, lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 42] (id : 140278039812000)
>>> a
['a', 'b', 'c', 42, [42]]
```

So in your `helper` function, you have this:

```
if index == len(set_list):
    if cur not in res:
        res.append(cur) # -> if I change this to res.append(cur[:]) this works
    return

helper(set_list, index + 1, res, cur)

cur.append(set_list[index]) # HERE
helper(set_list, index + 1, res, cur)
cur.pop() # AND HERE !!!!
```

Notice the `cur.append(xxx)` and `cur.pop()` calls ? Guess what ? Yes, they mutate the `cur` list. The one you appended to `res`. Which is why you end up with an empty result. It's rather obvious if you trace code execution:

```
def helper(set_list, index, res, cur):
    print("helper with index %s, res %s and cur %s" % (index, res, cur))

    if index == len(set_list):
        if cur not in res:
            print("append %s to %s" % (cur, res))
            res.append(cur) # -> if I change this to res.append(cur[:]) this works
        return

    print("first recursive call")
    helper(set_list, index + 1, res, cur)
    print("now res is %s and cur is %s" % (res, cur))

    print("appending to cur")
    cur.append(set_list[index])
    print("now cur is %s" % cur)

    print("second recursive call")
    helper(set_list, index + 1, res, cur)
    print("now res is %s and cur is %s" % (res, cur))

    print("poping from cur")
    cur.pop()
    print("now res is %s and cur is %s" % (res, cur))
```

which produces:

```
helper with index 0, res [] and cur []
first recursive call
helper with index 1, res [] and cur []
first recursive call
helper with index 2, res [] and cur []
first recursive call
helper with index 3, res [] and cur []
append [] to []
now res is [[]] and cur is []
appending to cur
now cur is [2]
second recursive call
helper with index 3, res [[2]] and cur [2]
now res is [[2]] and cur is [2]
poping from cur
now res is [[]] and cur is []
now res is [[]] and cur is []
appending to cur
now cur is [2]
second recursive call
helper with index 2, res [[2]] and cur [2]
first recursive call
helper with index 3, res [[2]] and cur [2]
now res is [[2]] and cur is [2]
appending to cur
now cur is [2, 2]
second recursive call
helper with index 3, res [[2, 2]] and cur [2, 2]
now res is [[2, 2]] and cur is [2, 2]
poping from cur
now res is [[2]] and cur is [2]
now res is [[2]] and cur is [2]
poping from cur
now res is [[]] and cur is []
now res is [[]] and cur is []
appending to cur
now cur is [1]
second recursive call
helper with index 1, res [[1]] and cur [1]
first recursive call
helper with index 2, res [[1]] and cur [1]
first recursive call
helper with index 3, res [[1]] and cur [1]
now res is [[1]] and cur is [1]
appending to cur
now cur is [1, 2]
second recursive call
helper with index 3, res [[1, 2]] and cur [1, 2]
now res is [[1, 2]] and cur is [1, 2]
poping from cur
now res is [[1]] and cur is [1]
now res is [[1]] and cur is [1]
appending to cur
now cur is [1, 2]
second recursive call
helper with index 2, res [[1, 2]] and cur [1, 2]
first recursive call
helper with index 3, res [[1, 2]] and cur [1, 2]
now res is [[1, 2]] and cur is [1, 2]
appending to cur
now cur is [1, 2, 2]
second recursive call
helper with index 3, res [[1, 2, 2]] and cur [1, 2, 2]
now res is [[1, 2, 2]] and cur is [1, 2, 2]
poping from cur
now res is [[1, 2]] and cur is [1, 2]
now res is [[1, 2]] and cur is [1, 2]
poping from cur
now res is [[1]] and cur is [1]
now res is [[1]] and cur is [1]
poping from cur
now res is [[]] and cur is []
[]
```

And which is why appending a shallow copy of `res` instead solves the issue - it's a different object, so it's not affected by the `cur.append()` and `cur.pop()` calls.

FWIW, there's [an exellent articles about this whole topic](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which you certainly want to read.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I definitely need to understand more about this. I was thinking shallow copy is like a pointer to an object so if anything changed the object the value of the pointer it points to should also be changed... looks like it's not what I thought, have to take a deeper look

Comment: If you come from the C world, you'll have to unlearn a couple things indeed. The article I linked to should definitly help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem while appending a list to another in a function.

As I said in my comment, we need more context to highlight the behavior...

```py
def append(l1, l2):
    l1.append(l2)

def extend(l1, l2):
    l1.extend(l2)

def main():
    append_l = ['a', 'b']
    extend_l = ['c', 'd']

    new = [1, 2, 3]

    print("Append")
    print(append_l)
    append(append_l, new)
    print(append_l)

    print("Extend")
    print(extend_l)
    extend(extend_l, new)
    print(extend_l)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
Append
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', [1, 2, 3]]
Extend
['c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 1, 2, 3]
```